# QMYSQL в Qt 5.6 Ubuntu x64

Tags: ubuntu, qt, qt5

Установил community версию Qt 5.6 в Ubuntu 16.04. Там же в ней стоит Qt 4.8 и с ним нет ни каких проблем. [Пытался разобраться самостоятельно](http://sitefresh.net/articles/43-qt-5-draiver-qmsql.html), но результат пока не проявляется.

```
#include <QtCore/QCoreApplication>
#include <db_connect.h>
#include <debugapi.h>
#include <action_user.h>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QPluginLoader>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    //Создание объекта консольного приложения
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    //DB_connect::createConnection();
    //Создание объекта сервера
    //QSimpleServer server;
    //Запуск цикла обработки событий
    QPluginLoader loader;
    loader.setFileName("/home/alexandr/Qt/5.6/gcc_64/plugins/sqldrivers/libqsqlmysql.so");
    qDebug() << loader.load();
    qDebug() << loader.errorString();

    QStringList PathList = a.libraryPaths();

    PathList.append(a.applicationDirPath() + "/plugins");
    a.setLibraryPaths(PathList);
    qDebug() << a.libraryPaths().join(";");

    Action_user action;
    DebugAPI api;
    action.CommandSplit(api.addUser());
    qDebug () << api.addUser();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Вывод в консоль:

```
false
"Cannot load library /home/alexandr/Qt/5.6/gcc_64/plugins/sqldrivers/libqsqlmysql.so: (libssl.so.10: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)"
"/home/alexandr/Qt/5.6/gcc_64/plugins;/home/alexandr/Documents/Job/build-ThreadedServer-Desktop_Qt_5_6_0_GCC_64bit-Debug;/home/alexandr/Documents/Job/build-ThreadedServer-Desktop_Qt_5_6_0_GCC_64bit-Debug/plugins"
addUser
QSqlDatabase: QMYSQL driver not loaded
QSqlDatabase: available drivers: QSQLITE QPSQL QPSQL7
("QSQLITE", "QPSQL", "QPSQL7")
Cannot open database:  QSqlError("", "Driver not loaded", "Driver not loaded")

~/Qt/5.6/gcc_64/plugins/sqldrivers$ objdump -x libqsqlmysql.so | grep NEEDED
  NEEDED               libmysqlclient_r.so.16
  NEEDED               libz.so.1
  NEEDED               libcrypt.so.1
  NEEDED               libnsl.so.1
  NEEDED               libssl.so.10
  NEEDED               libcrypto.so.10
  NEEDED               libQt5Sql.so.5
  NEEDED               libQt5Core.so.5
  NEEDED               libpthread.so.0
  NEEDED               libstdc++.so.6
  NEEDED               libm.so.6
  NEEDED               libgcc_s.so.1
  NEEDED               libc.so.6
```

Имется:

```
/usr/lib/libmysqlclient_r.so.16
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libz.so.1
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1
/lib32/libnsl.so.1
/libx32/libnsl.so.1
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnsl.so.1
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnsl.so.1
/lib32/libpthread.so.0
/libx32/libpthread.so.0
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
/usr/lib32/libstdc++.so.6
/usr/libx32/libstdc++.so.6
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
/usr/lib/libssl.so.10
/usr/lib/libcrypto.so.10
/usr/lib/libQt5Sql.so.5
/usr/lib/libQt5Core.so.5
/usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6
/usr/lib/libgcc_s.so.1
/lib32/libm.so.6
/libx32/libm.so.6
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm.so.6
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6
/lib32/libc.so.6
/libx32/libc.so.6
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get install libssl1.0.0 libssl-dev     
sudo ln -s /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0 /usr/lib/libssl.so.10
sudo ln -s /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 /usr/lib/libcrypto.so.10
```